# How to get key from SelectedItem of ComboBox?

Tags: c#, combobox, keyvaluepair

I am trying to get the key of `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` but do not figure it out how to get code which I have done is,

```
void CboBoxSortingDatagridview(ComboBox sender)
{
    foreach (var v in DictionaryCellValueNeeded)
    {
        if (!DictionaryGeneralUsers.ContainsKey(v.Key) && v.Value.RoleId == Convert.ToInt32(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem)) // here getting value {1,Admin} i want key value which is 1 but how?
        {
            DictionaryGeneralUsers.Add(v.Key, (GeneralUser)v.Value);
        }
    }
    dataGridViewMain.DataSource = DictionaryGeneralUsers.Values;
}
```

I binded the combo box in this way,

```
cboRolesList.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionaryRole, null);  
cboRolesList.DisplayMember = "Value";  
cboRolesList.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In cases like this, dictionaries are simply collections of key-value pairs, so each item on the `ComboBox` is a `KeyValuePair<YourKeyType, YourValueType>`. Cast `SelectedItem` to a `KeyValuePair<YourKeyType, YourValueType>` and then you can read the key.

```
// get ComboBox from sender
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

// get selected KVP
KeyValuePair<YourKeyType, YourValueType> selectedEntry
    = (KeyValuePair<YourKeyType, YourValueType>) comboBox.SelectedItem;

// get selected Key
YourKeyType selectedKey = selectedEntry.Key;
```

Or, a simpler way is to use the `SelectedValue` property.

```
// get ComboBox from sender
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

// get selected Key
YourKeyType selectedKey = (YourKeyType) comboBox.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Your simpler way gives an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @iheanyi Did you set `ValueMember`, as shown in the original post? From [the documentation of SelectedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_SelectedValue): "If a property is not specified in ValueMember, SelectedValue returns the results of the ToString method of the object."

Comment: I retract my previous comment. It turns out that I had not set `ValueMember`. I actually had two combo boxes, copy-pasted code and forgot to change the combo box name on the one whose `ValueMember` I actually cared about. The names were similar enough that it took a while to realize my error, even after making several edits to the code.

Comment: I'd tried it out and got the error referenced in my first comment. Convinced that I'd done nothing wrong, I downvoted your answer. I only realized my error after it was too late to undo the downvote w/o requiring an edit to your answer.

Comment: @iheanyi You can undo the downvote just by clicking the downvote arrow again.

Comment: After a certain period of time, you can't undo a downvote that way unless the answer is edited. We passed that period before I realized I was wrong.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139949/unable-to-undo-downvote

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I never knew that rule. No big deal. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

string key = ((KeyValuePair < string, string > )comboBox1.SelectedItem).Key;

Comment: I couldnt get past the InvalidCastException from the answer above (I am sure my fault), This one worked well. Thanks